# open DataReader associated issue

Tags: acumatica

I need to release the Production Order Maintenance document from other graph, and when am calling release.press(), am facing data reader issue, can some one please help me, Please have a look at below code

```
using (new PXConnectionScope())
 {
   ProdMaintGraph.ProdItemSelected.Current = ProdItem;
   ProdMaintGraph.release.Press();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `Release(PXAdapter adapter)` function!

```
AMProdItem prodItem = null;//your current record
ProdMaint prodMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProdMaint>();
prodMaint.ProdMaintRecords.Current =prodMaint.ProdMaintRecords.Search<AMProdItem.orderType, AMProdItem.prodOrdID>(prodItem?.OrderType, prodItem?.ProdOrdID);
var adapterProdMaint = new PXAdapter(prodMaint.ProdMaintRecords, new string[]
  {
     prodMaint.ProdMaintRecords.Current?.OrderType,
     prodMaint.ProdMaintRecords.Current?.ProdOrdID
  }); 
prodMaint.Release(adapter);//Run 'Release Order' action 
prodMaint.ReleaseMaterial(adapter);//Run 'Release Material' action
```